# How to spread requests over specific times in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMETER and having some trouble understanding how to spread requests over specific times

I need to run the test for 16 hours and spread it as follows:

1. Morning shift – “low traffic”: 07:00-15:00 (8h) – 20% of total traffic
2. Noon shift – “high traffic”: 15:00-19:00 (4h) – 50% of total traffic
3. Evening shift 1 - “very high traffic”: 19:00-20:00 (1h) – 20% of total traffic
4. Evening shift 2 - “low traffic”: 20:00-23:59 (3h) – 10% of total traffic

- traffic is the whatever number of requests that comes from 500 threads, 500 ramp-up and 1000 loops

so for example we have 100,000 requests, I need:

20% of it in the Morning shift thread group over 8 hours
50% of it in the Noon shift thread group over 4 hours
20% of it in the Evening shift 1 thread group over 1 hour
and 10% of it in the Evening shift 2 thread group over 3 hours

[image]

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

This can help you spread your load over time. Please have a look at the documentation and you should be done

Answer (score 1):

> traffic is the whatever number of requests that comes from 500 threads, 500 ramp-up and 1000 loops

the aforementioned configuration results in **`500 000` total requests**

So you need to send 500k requests in 16 hours out of which:

- Morning shift - 100 000 requests in 8 hours (100 000 requests in 28800 seconds == 3.472222222222222 requests per second)
- Noon shift - 250 000 requests in 4 hours (250 000 requests in 14400 seconds == 17.36111111111111 requests per second)
- Evening shift 1 - 100 000 requests in 1 hour (100 000 requests in 3600 seconds == 27.77777777777778 requests per second)
- Evening shift 2 - 50 000 requests in 3 hours (50 000 requests in 10800 seconds == 4.62962962962963 requests per second)

I would recommend going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination, example setup:

[image]